# Upper bound on the number of permutations in a set during an algorithm

Tags: co.combinatorics, symmetric-groups

Fix $n\geq 2$ and let $S_n$ be the symmetric group on $n$ letters with identity $e$. We consider elements of $S_n$ to be bijections $[n]\to [n]$ as well as sequences (one line notation). For $1\leq i<n$, let $s_i$ be the transposition exchanging $i$ and $i+1$. Consider the following algorithm that successively constructs subsets $A_N\subseteq S_n$.

1. Let $A_0=\{e\}$.
2. At step $K$, remove the least element from $A_K$ in lexicographical order, say $f\in A_K$, and for each subset $B\subseteq [n-1]$ such that if $B=\{b_1,\ldots,b_m\}$, then $|b_i-b_j|\geq 2$ for all $i\neq j$ and $f(b_i)<f(b_{i}+1)$ for all $i$, add the permutation $fs_{b_1}s_{b_2}\cdots s_{b_m}$ to $A_K$. (In weak order, this will add all maximal elements of Boolean algebra intervals with minimal element $f$). After this one removal and all such additions we obtain the set $A_{K+1}$.

Step 2 is repeated until the ultimate set is empty. The penultimate set will contain only the longest element, the reversal permutation.

I'm interested in estimating the number $M_n$ defined by
$$M_n=\max_{K}{|A_K|}$$
We have
$$M_5\leq 0.32\cdot 5!$$
$$M_6\leq  0.3125\cdot 6!$$
$$M_7\leq 0.294\cdot 7!$$
$$M_8\leq 0.292\cdot 8!$$
$$M_9\leq 0.282\cdot 9!$$
$$M_{10}\leq 0.2811\cdot 10!$$
$$M_{11}\leq 0.2753\cdot 11!$$
$$M_{12}\leq 0.2749\cdot 12!$$
This will be the amount of space required in my algorithm for computing the sequence http://oeis.org/A006245. To me it seems $M_n$ is just as hard to compute as this sequence, which is why I'm looking for an estimate. I'm mostly interested in $n=16$, since this is the first unknown value. If $M_{16}$ is around $0.27\cdot 16!$, then it's not feasible at the moment to do the computation, whereas if it's $0.2\cdot 16!$ it might be.

Comment: I think the quickest answer will be to compute M13 through M15 first.  I do not understand the description well enough to estimate it for you. (Sizes for small n,  say n =6, as well as Ak for small k might help. Even knowing if Ak sizes is a unimodular sequence and for which k there is a peak might help.). I encourage you to post an answer with more detail, so that people can refer to the detail separately.  Gerhard "Even Though Not An Answer" Paseman, 2017.11.30.

Comment: In which of 4 possible directions does your lexicographical order go? (from the beginning or from the end, increasing or decreasing?)

Comment: @fedja From the beginning, increasing. Literally alphabetical order.

Comment: So $15423< 31452$, right? (just to make sure that we have no misunderstanding here)

Comment: @fedja Yes. This comment is too short.

Comment: It is not clear to me if 1) the bi in B are ordered so bi is less than b(i+1) 2) you add all permutations of B by 'also' adding fb2b1... 3) If B is used and C is a proper subset of B then C is also used.  Dumb question, but maybe a lower bound of what does not get put in would help: is there a characterization of permutations that never get added?  Gerhard "Sometimes Not Solving Is Easier" Paseman, 2017.11.30.

Comment: @Ger 1) It doesn't matter if they're ordered, by the condition that they differ by at least $2$ it follows that the transpositions commute. 2) those are all the same permutation. 3) Yes, because $C$ would be another subset of the same type.

Comment: OK. Your use of maximal, while correct, throws me off because I think of maximal intervals as well.  Gerhard "Understanding Is Not Yet Maximal" Paseman, 2017.11.30.

Comment: Also, since you are "comparing" them with f, the order of the b's does matter.  However, if you are iterating over all permutations of all subsets, then you can show what you do is equivalent to "picking your favorite ordering of B" that gets the job done.  Gerhard "It's About Getting It Done" Paseman, 2017.11.30.

Comment: If the ordering of $b$ does not matter, what does the condition $f(b_i)<f(b_{i+1})$ mean? (One can reorder any set $B$ according to $f(b)$.

Comment: @fedja I meant $f(b_i)<f(b_i+1)$. Sorry about that.

Comment: Based on the numerics given for 5 through 12, I predict 0.24* 16! is a lower bound.  Gerhard "Bordering The Chasm Of Unfeasability" Paseman, 2017.12.01.

Comment: @Gerhard The amount of space required is at the bare minimum 22 bytes times $M_{16}$. That's many terabytes. No computer I know of has enough RAM, so it will involve permanent storage, which is slow. With RAM it would already take thousands of hours. I'm confident it will eventually be feasible, but not sure about now.

Comment: How long would it take at present to compute M13 and M14? Days or weeks?  Gerhard "Also Has Problems With Memory" Paseman, 2017.12.01.

Comment: @Gerhard 13 one or two days, 14 maybe a week or two, 15 several weeks. For any of those values though I need to obtain more memory, so it's not something I can readily do at the moment.

Comment: @Gerhard Estimate I need about 175GB to compute n=13. I could've done that on the computer I had access to when I was a student, but with my current computer (which is actually a server at the company I work at that really shouldn't be used for this) I only have 72GB of RAM and even less disk space

Comment: Might be worth looking at EC2: 4TB instances are available now (x1e.32xlarge) with 16TB in the pipeline. Of course you have to get your wallet out ..

Comment: @J.J. My most optimistic estimation using Gerhard's answer is 113TB for n=16. 16TB could get me n=15, which is already known.

Comment: Could you explain the 22 bytes?  0..15 fits in 4 bits, and 16 of those is 8 bytes. Perhaps I'm being dense here ...

Comment: If there were a linear relationship between M_n and the OEIS sequence, he probably would not need much memory.  My guess is that for each permutation he has to compute a value, and then add them up.  The 22 bytes probably holds additional structure he is using for the value computation.  Gerhard "That's How I'd Do It" Paseman, 2017.12.01.

Comment: Yes, the 22 bytes includes a massively compressed representation of the permutation together with a 128-bit integer.

Comment: @J.J. I could distribute it across 8 16TB instances. However, that would cost a fortune, and I'm not employed by a school or research institution so I doubt I can get a grant.

Comment: @MattSamuel : I know that feeling, I'm in a similar situation myself.  Why not be cheeky and ask for a freebie? EC2, Azure etc have plenty of smart kids who will see the intrinsic value, and it would make a good press release for them, so has business value too.  At worst they can say no.

Comment: @J.J. worth a shot. I managed to get it down to 16 bytes per permutation, so about 87 TB. I can't think of any other space optimizations. Oddly enough this compressed representation is actually faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have bad news.  The (constant for large n for your) upper bound will never drop below 1/4.  Thus my prediction in a comment above will hold.

A key observation is that every permutation sits in one of the A_k, and so you will run through this n factorial times. One way to see this is that  by induction every permutation of the smaller elements is generated, and then take up to n-1 steps to move the largest element in position.  If I had known this yesterday, I could have answered sooner.

With this observation, we can see a key property.  Setting m =(n-1)!, we process all the permutations beginning with 1 so that A_m has exactly those permutations with second element 1.  One can then conclude the nature of A_jm: It is all permutations with first element larger than j and second element j or less. This gives a lower bound on the constant of (n-j)*j/(n(n-1)), which is bounded from below by 1/4 when j is floor(n/2).

You can extend this to analyze A_(jm +r) where r is a multiple of a smaller factorial.  For a Starbucks card I might extend the analysis for you, especially if the sequence is algebraically related to M_n. For programming purposes, the idea that the upper bound is not far from 1/4 (maybe 1/4 times (1 + 1/(n-2)?) should suffice for your planning.

Gerhard "Proofreads For Starbucks Cards Too" Paseman, 2017.12.01.

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually trying to compute $M_{13}$ because I realized there's a way to do it using far less memory.

Comment: You're welcome.  I recommend trying n=7 and n=8 and checking my characterization of A_jm.  If I have it right, you can probably use it to speed up your computation of M16 as well.  Gerhard "Don't Call It A Monster" Paseman, 2017.12.01.

Comment: @MattSamuel Interesting. If we have such a clear idea of what $A_K$ are at least sometimes, why should we keep all their elements in the memory in the literal sense? If not a secret, how does your algorithm use them?

Comment: @fedja It's not a secret. It's actually the iterative version of the Maple code on the sequence web page (which is recursive). You take the value at the node you remove and add it to the values at the nodes you add, with a sign of $(-1)^{|B|}$. The value at the identity is $1$ in the first step. The result is the final value at the longest element.

Comment: Of course, I should add that for n=16, the constant is above 0.266666 (4/15), so it looks like you need to rearrange memory usage, perhaps writing to disk.  Gerhard "Good Luck With Massive Computation" Paseman, 2017.12.06.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Thanks. I think I've actually come up with the minimum possible space usage and that ends up being 87TB (assuming a constant of 0.275). It doesn't store the permutations at all. It uses the rank in lexicographical order as an index into a paged array, so 16 bytes per permutation, give or take an extra megabyte. Theoretically you could arrange it so that the actual space usage is terrible because they're spread out across pages, but they actually seem to cluster together pretty nicely, and I've been able to get n=13 in 13GB of memory, which is available to me.

Comment: Indeed.  By differential encoding (which is probably close to what you are using), you can reduce the storage further.  But you have been working on this a while and probably have considered most of the possibilities for representation.  Gerhard "May There Be No Error" Paseman, 2017.12.06.

Comment: @Gerhard I made a massive speed optimization and afterwards it occurred to me to try to accurately estimate how long it would take to calculate $n=16$. ,I got 13 years. Looks like we're going to have to try to parallelize it.